# How to mention different timezone in different targets for NLog C#

Tags: c#, timezone, nlog

I am using NLog in my project, I have created different targets and associated rules. I have even created a [Custom Time Zone](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Time-Source) for the time attributes in log, which shows the in EST zone in my logging targets.

```
 <time type="CustomTimeZone" zone="Eastern Standard Time" />
```

Is there a way to specify different custom time sources for different targets? As an example, I want to display UTC time in my console, EST time in file and probably some other time in a different log target.

I felt the custom time zone implementation affects the whole NLog environment, and Google wasn't too helpful. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `${date:universalTime=true}` can be used, if wanting output in UTC at a specific place. See also https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Date-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Hi @RolfKristensen , many thanks for this suggestion. Using this I am able to set a custom timezone for my regular targets and use UTC for a particular target. Is there a way to force it to local time in similar manner when having a custom timezone source? i.e. use a custom time zone source, say CST for global, force a target to use UTC and force another to use EST (my local)?

Comment: You are welcome to create a pull-request for the NLog-project that extends the `${date}`-LayoutRenderer to have a TimeZone-property. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pulls

Comment: Hi @RolfKristensen, thank you!! So there is no option to force local time in a date layout currently? Like just by adding something similar to 'FastUtc/ FastLocal' in date parameter? I will add the request if this is not present.

Comment: Not that experienced with the NLog Time-source system. I only use `AccurateUTC` because I like speed and time-precision.

Comment: Hi @RolfKristensen AccurateUTC / AccurateLocal parameters are for the whole environment right, I can not chose them for individual targets, like one target for UTC and another for local, keeping the global time as EST ?

Comment: You are asking the same question over and over. And I have already answered that I don't know much about Nlog-time-source, and suggested that you create a pull-request the NLog-project to extend `${date}`-LayoutRenderer to have a TimeZone-property. If you want a different answer, then you should not be asking me :)

Comment: Really!! great :)